# Prevent users from stealing remote sessions (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, session

We have multiple users logging into the same computer remotely with the same account using Windows Remote Desktop. If somebody is currently remotely logged in, another person would only get a note about that if he tries to log in using a different account.

But when using the same account, you simply steal the other person's session. 
Is there any possibility to receive a warning that an active remote desktop connection with this account is already active when trying to log in?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very secure setup. A better option would be a [Terminal Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_server)

Comment: "Is there any possibility to receive a warning that an active remote desktop connection with this account is already active when trying to log in?"  - **Of course there is.** Stop using a single user and a consumer version of Windows 7.  Windows Server 2008 R2 will allow multiple users to login at once.

Comment: There are a few reasons why we use a single account. For example there is a Virtual machine running under this account and multiple persons need access to it. So getting Windows Server License won't be of any help, because the two users won't be able to use the VM at the same time.